# ExecutorService invokeall threadpool issue

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am struggling with a use case where one of the tasks submitted to `invokeall()` throws `CancellationException` forcing program NOT to terminate. How can make sure this program will terminate properly in case of `CancellationException` ?

How I am finding out my program not terminated clean? I am using netbeans and shows progress bar at bottom right if program doesn't terminate.

Here is code:

```
        int poolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        Set<Callable<Object>> tasksSet = new HashSet<>();
        tasksSet.add(new Task1());
        tasksSet.add(new Task2());
        tasksSet.add(new Task3());

       List<Future<TrendLineStatisticsVO>> resultSet = pool.invokeAll(tasksSet, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        for (Future<Object> future : resultSet) {
            Object result;
            try {
                   result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        pool.shutdown();
```

And `Task1` code:

```
public class Task1 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
       //This for sure takes days to complete, so should through Cancellation exception because    timeout on invokeall set to 1 minute
        long val = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE - 5000; i++) {
            val += i;
        }
        return "Sucessfull Task1 object...";
    }

}
```

`Task2` and `Task3` code also same except these two classes use Integer.MAX_VALUE in for loop check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1)

Per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

So you will have to code your `Task` to be responsive to interruption.  What is happening in the background is similar to `future.cancel(true)` if the tasks don't complete in the time specified, the true in the argument says to `interrupt()` the thread running the task.  Like I mentioned, your tasks will have to look out for interruption.  Something similar to:

```
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
   //This for sure takes days to complete, so should through Cancellation exception because    timeout on invokeall set to 1 minute
    long val = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE - 5000; i++) {
        if(Thread.interruped()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not complete in time: " + i);
        }
        val += i;
    }
    return "Sucessfull Task1 object...";
}
```

> How I am finding out my program not terminated clean? I am using netbeans and shows progress bar at bottom right if program doesn't terminate.

Without my update above the program will never end as the thread pool is still running.  `shutdown` will do nothing as the tasks haven't completed (event with cancel).

2)

A task that is cancelled, by definition, did not complete (or even start) so invoking `get` on the Future will fail quickly.  You could ask the future if it's cancelled `Future#isCancelled`.

Comment: I have small followup if you don't mind, in this case instead of for loop, let us say we are calling 10 different methods, which does some operations, problem is we don't know where the control is by the time we reach time out, then how can we handle interrupt here? any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to handle that use case.  For instance, what if one of the other methods is reading from an `InputStream` in which the `read()` method does not respond to interruption.  You may be out of luck (unless you can, say close that InputStream).

Comment: So my answer to your question is, it depends.  This is why concurrent programming is so difficult.  You will have to investigate what is going on and if the functions you are calling respond to interruption, if not, see if there is a way you can get the method to end.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I have full control over the methods, so I can add guards to terminate the Thread, but in general where user don't have control on checking interrupted life will be miserable, in my opinion java platform should provide and honor force cleanup for these threads to avoid resource leak.

Comment: If you are running a simple Java app with main method and you want it just to end when the main method finishes, you have two outs.  One `Thread.stop`, this is widely deprecated and not recommended for various reasons (read up maybe it can help). Or two, you can declare the Thread as daemon via `setDaemon(true)`.  What a daemon thread does, is when all non-daemon threads are completed, the application will forcibly shut down. When you run a simple java app the main thread would be the only non-daemon thread so when the main method ends, the app will end.

Comment: No it is not standalone app. Those two options may not work fome. Code I posted in this question is quick standalone skeleton.